# I have two tables,from that am fetching data with left join

Tags: php

post id is the common field in both the tables.If I want to select the comments under same post_id,only 1 time the post should display and all its comments under it..
this is my code....

home.php

```
<?php

$sql="SELECT family_news.post_id,family_news.username,family_news.post,
            family_news.fileToUpload,family_news.description,
            family_comments.post_id,family_comments.comment,
            family_comments.commenter 
     FROM family_news 
        LEFT JOIN family_comments ON family_news.post_id = family_comments.post_id 
     ORDER BY family_news.post_id DESC";

if($result =  mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>

    <div class="form-group">
    <b style="font-size:30px;color:brown;">

    <?php
        echo $row['username'];
    ?>
    </b>
    <br>
        <?php 
        if($row['fileToUpload'] != NULL)
        {
        ?>
     <form action="post_comment.php" method="POST">
            <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $row['post_id']; ?>">
           <br>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="../admin_panel/uploads/<?php echo $row['fileToUpload']; ?>" alt="Image Loading" height='80' width='120'>
        <div class="form-group" style="font-size:15px;color:purple;">
            <?php
                echo $row['description'];
            ?>
            <br>
            <h3 style="color:black">Comments</h3>
            <h3 style="color:red">
            <?php
                echo $row['commenter'];
            ?>
            </h3>
            <h4 style="color:saddlebrown">
            <?php
                echo $row['comment'];
            ?>
            </h4>

            <br>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Write a comment">
            <br>
            <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="commenter" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['uname']; ?>">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Post"> 

        </div>
    </form>
        <?php 
        }
        if($row['post'] != NULL)
        {
        ?>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group" style="font-size:15px;color:purple;">
            <form action="post_comment.php" method="POST">
            <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $row['post_id']; ?>">
            <?php
            echo $row['post'];
            ?>
            <br>
            <h3 style="color:black">Comments</h3>
            <h3 style="color:red">
            <?php
                echo $row['commenter'];
            ?>
            </h3>
            <h4 style="color:saddlebrown">
            <?php
                echo $row['comment'];
            ?>
            </h4>
            <br>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Write a comment">
            <br>
            <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="commenter" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['uname']; ?>">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Post"> 
            </form>
<?php
        }
?>
</div>
<?php
    }
}

?>
    </div>

</section>
```

post_comment.php

```
<section class="col-lg-6 connectedSortable">

<?php
$post_id=$_POST['post_id'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$commenter=$_POST['commenter'];

if($comment != NULL) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO family_comments 
                (post_id, comment, commenter) 
          VALUES ('$post_id', '$comment', '$commenter')";

    if($con ->query($sql) == TRUE)
    {
        echo 'Comment saved Successfully...';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Please Write Something...';
}
?>



</section>
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: If I understood corectly you want the data about the post once, and all the comments. With your select (one to many) you will get the post details for every comment. You can try with two selects. First, you select your post then, for this post id you get all the comments.

Comment: okey....thank you  @Vladut...that was the actual problem